# Regular expression to find a string that begins with > and ends with }

Tags: javascript, php, regex, perl, abap

May I know how to write regular expression to get the string that starts with `>` and ends with `}`?

**Example string** :

```
data>/ab/cd/peter} ;gopal came prop>/site/sing/perl};
```

I want the following sub-strings:

```
>/ab/cd/peter}
>site/sing/perl}
```

I tried with this but not knowing how place a condition that starts with `>`
my findings:

```
(\/(\w+)\/)*(\w+)(@*)(\w+)(~*)((\w+)?)\/(\w+)\}
```

Comment: try this `(?<=>).+?(?=})` if you want > and } then `(>).+?(})`

Comment: Which language? javascript, php, perl, abap ?

Answer (score 3):

It's just `/>[^}]+}/g`: `>` to mark where to start, `[^}]+` to say "anything that isn't a `}`" one or more times, and `}` to mark where to stop:

```js
const str = "data>/ab/cd/peter} ;gopal came prop>/site/sing/perl};";
const rex = />[^}]+}/g;
let match;
while (!!(match = rex.exec(str))) {
  console.log(match[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex of javascript :

```
var inputStr = "data>/ab/cd/peter} ;gopal came prop>/site/sing/perl};";

var outputStr = inputStr.match(/(\>)([^\>\}]*)(\})/g);
console.log(outputStr);
```

Comment: Thanks Worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

In ABAP, you must escape `}`. Converting the right answer by @T.J. Crowder, this gives:

```
FIND ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX '>[^}]+\}' IN 'data>/ab/cd/peter} ;gopal came prop>/site/sing/perl};' RESULTS DATA(results).
```